# LinkedIn API Data Expires

Tags: api, linkedin-api, profile

When obtaining data, like user profile pictures, through the official LinkedIn API Oauth 2.0, the link returned expires after a random number of days and returns a 403.

Needless to say, when a user profile is created, I wish for this link to point to the correct user image on LinkedIn indefinitely.

Is there a way to obtain a URL that does not expire?

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin return the profile image URL.It can be expired when user changes their profile image from linkedin.So You should download the image into your server.You can use below function to upload remote url image.

```
$path_info=pathinfo($url);
$filename='image_name.jpg';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$upload =file_put_contents('/path_to_folder'.$filename, $data);
```

You can look into the webhooks to receive instant updates.